# Match two arrays with condition

Tags: jquery

I have table without td/th-id's/classes and I loop through the table to get the data from the td:s. If there is no data or data is: "-" then I set a CSS-class on that td. Like this:

```
$('.simpletable td').each(function() {
 if($(this).text() === '-')
  {
    $(this).addClass("nodata");
  }
});
```

However I need to match that 'td' with the corresponding 'th' to set the same CSS-class. I fetch an array for the th-array with:

```
$('.simpletable th').each(function()
{
    tableheaders.push($(this).text());
});
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Or is there a simpler way to do all of this this if I start from scratch?

This table has several rows of 'th' so I cant really do anything with columns.

MARKUP html:

```
<table class="simpletable">
<thead>
    <th>th1</th>
    <th>th2</th>
    <th>th3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>data 1</td>
        <td>-</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
    </tr>
<thead>
<th>th4</th>
<th>th5</th>
<th>th6</th>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>data 4 row 2</td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td>data 6 row 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: There's a couple of things you can do.  First, to solve your *immediate* problem, you can use the `:eq()` selector and `index()` function.  `var index = $(this).index();`, then for your th `$('th:eq(' + index + ')'` will select the `th` that is the same column as the `td`.  Secondly, there is a such thing as a `text` selector: https://api.jquery.com/text-selector/ - you may be able to leverage this like so: `$('.simpletable td[text="-']').each(`, which would only select the cells that have text equal to `=`

Comment: @ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ You should undelete your answer, it turns out to be correct because of the clarification of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the index of the `td` then use [.filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) to get the appropriate `th` that have the same column index

```
$('.simpletable td').each(function() {
 if($(this).text() === '-')
  {
    $(this).addClass("nodata");
    var ind = $(this).index(); // get td index relative to it's row
    $('.simpletable th').filter(function(i,v){
        return $(v).index() == ind; // only return th with same column index as the td
    }).addClass('nodata');
  }
});
```

Comment: Are you sure about `i`? Isn't that going to return the wrong value if there's more than one row - or is it the index within the context of the given `tr`?